# SQL - Fetch RSS feeds and insert into SQL

Tags: php, mysql, curl, pdo, rss

**Question:** How to Fetch and Insert RSS FEED into MySQL? 
I want to fetch and insert data from an rss feed, in this case kotakus rss feed (*kotaku.com/vip.xml*) .

Currently: i get an error with PDO method: 
Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '(' in D:\xampp\htdocs\xml\sql_pdo.php on line 11

I'll show Code for three steps. **First** to Fetch Data that is currently working. **Second** is a PDO method to fetch&insert data into mySQL ( not working currently ). **Third** is same as two but using Curl instead (not working either). Im using PhpMyAdmin and Xampp for the MySQL database. I just want either second or third method or another method to work.. only thing that matters is to get results.

First Code:

```
<?php
$xml= simplexml_load_file("http://kotaku.com/vip.xml"); 
foreach($xml->channel->item as $itm){
    $title = $itm->title;
    $description = $itm->description;
    echo $title;
    echo $description;
} ?>
```

Second (PDO)

```
<?php
$db = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=simpledata','root','123456');

$xmldoc = new DOMDocument();
$xmldoc = load('http://kotaku.com/vip.xml');

$xmldata = $xmldoc->getElementsByTagName('channel');
$xmlcount = $xmldata->length;

for ($i=0; $i < $xmlcount; $i++) {
    $title = $xmldata->item($i)->getElementsByTagName('title')(0)->childNodes->item(0)->nodeValue;
    $description = $xmldata->item($i)->getElementsByTagName('description')(0)->childNodes->item(0)->nodeValue;

    $stmt = $db->prepare("insert into kotaku values(?,?)");
    $stmt->bindParam(1,$title);
    $stmt->bindParam(1,$description);
    $stmt->execute();
    printf($title);
} ?>
```

Third (CURL)

```
<?php

$url="http://kotaku.com/vip.xml"; //need complete
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER,1);
curl-setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);  //get the url contents

$data = curl_exec ($ch); //execute curl request
curl_close($ch);

$xml = simplexml_load_string($data);

$con=mysql_connect("localhost","root","123456"); //connect to server 
mysql_select_db("simpledata", $con) or die (mysql_error()); //select database

foreach ($xml -> item as $row) {
    $title = $row -> title;
    $description = $row -> description;

// performing sql query

$sql = "INSERT INTO 'kotaku' ('title', 'description')"
        . "VALUES ('$title', '$description')";

$result = mysql_query($sql);
if (!$result) {
    echo 'MySQL ERROR';
    } else {
    echo 'SUCCES';
    }
?>
```

Comment: Sorry I forgot to say, I get an error with PDO method. 

Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '(' in D:\xampp\htdocs\xml\sql_pdo.php on line 11

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cant use pdo bindParam without specifying the binding data type.
Use bindValue instead:

```
  $stmt->bindValue(1, $title);
  $stmt->bindValue(2, $description);
```

Comment: Sorry I forgot to say, I get an error with PDO method. 

Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '(' in D:\xampp\htdocs\xml\sql_pdo.php on line 11

Even when using that method, Michael Dawn.

Comment: $title = $xmldata->item($i)->getElementsByTagName('title')(0)->childNodes->item(0)->nodeValue; @michael dawn

Comment: Can you echo the title and see what it displays and let me know

Comment: Well i get this result with First Code: The one just extracting the rss feed. 

https://snag.gy/uz1JCa.jpg . It is also pretty hard to show as you can't use "simplexml_load_file" in most php fiddles online. I've to get the results from localhost (xampp server). Not even Godaddy.com allows me to fetch from an rss feed.

Comment: Try the rss parser in the first code with pdo in the second code with my changes on the bindvalue

Comment: I give you right. I found an Youtube displaying another way. I will try what you wrote but putting pieces togather like a puzzle seems alittle complex. However thanks for reply and answer. @

Comment: Glad to help @Doe. J